# how can i hide whole table according to row count

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project about e-commercial website. I have problem with Cart section. I want to show one table if there is some goods on cart but if there is no i wanna show another table.

Here is my HTML code for tables

```
    <div class="sepet">
  <div id="dialog" title="Ürün Açıklaması">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </div>
  <table id="sepettablo" align="center" class="roundedCorners">
    <tr>
      <th>Ürün</th>
      <th>Açıklama</th>
      <th>Adet</th>
      <th>Birim Fiyatı</th>
      <th>Fiyat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\5.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\6.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\3.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\4.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toplam">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
            onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
        <td>Toplam:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="sepetbos" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Sepetiniz boş. Ürün eklemek ister misiniz?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

there it is. I have a function about deleting rows but it's just deleting rows. I want to disappear all table and show another table (class=sepetbos). and it must be according to the row count (first and last row included)

Comment: i know another question about this topic but it did not helped me on this problem. so please do not close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know the other question about this topic, I cannot know whether this will be any more helpful, but you could add a function like :

```
    function displayOneTable() {
        const cartTable = document.querySelector('table#sepettablo');
        const emptyTable = document.querySelector('table.sepetbos');
        //hopefully you only have 1 table with class='sepetbos' 
        //[would be better to set a unique id]

        var cartRows = cartTable.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
        if (cartRows > 0) {//use (cartRows>2) if header/total doesn't count
            emptyTable.setAttribute('hidden', true);

            cartTable.setAttribute('hidden', false);
            cartTable.removeAttribute('hidden');
        } else {
            cartTable.setAttribute('hidden', true);

            emptyTable.setAttribute('hidden', false);
            emptyTable.removeAttribute('hidden');
        }
    }
```

-- then you can call it once in your script so that in runs at when page is first rendered and also in whatever function/s remove (and/or add) rows from the cart table.